# How to setup https for instances beside a elastic load balancer which already have https

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have setup a `elastic load balancer` and created a `self signed certificate` for it. After uploading the `certificate` and `private key` on ELB and attaching an instance with ELB, the `https` and `http` request are working fine. For self signed certificate one can accept the certificate and access the website.
But I want to setup `https` between `ELB` and the `instance`. How to do this? Does the same ssl certificate which I created should be setup on the instance and configured with `nginx`? 
How to make ELB to accept the SSL certificate of the instance?